# if I close a java program while it is excuting a synchronized function will it complete

Tags: java, synchronized

using Java

I have done some research before asking here but I was still unable to find an answer. I am writing an application that connects to twitter's streaming api and receives some tweets. I intend to run the program for a few hours and then I need to interrupt it.

There is no multi-threading so far in my project and I am trying to avoid that. If I make the function that gets the tweet synchronized, would it complete even if I closed the program while it's executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no multi-threading in your application, why do you need `synchronized`? Never mind, your application will complete. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will just interrupt all threads and shutdown nicely.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't complete. Synchronization doesn't prevent `System.exit()` to exit.

That said, unless you use Ctrl-C to kill your program, you have some multi-threading in the project. Else you wouldn't be able to call `System.exit()` while another method is executing.